# Locating minimum on table/output

Tags: r, minimum

[image: table]

(R studio)

Basic question about how to go about finding the minimum of a value on a table.

The table is longer than this (nsplit goes to 1532), which is why I'm looking for a search function.

In the picture basically I'd like to find the minimum value of "xerror", and after that I'd like to find "nsplit" at the minimum of "xerror"

I'd definitely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code (assuming the name of your data frame is d):

```
d[which(d$xerror==min(d$xerror)),]
```

With this code you can find values of every other variables (including "nsplit") at the minimum value of "xerror". You can also see which observation it is at the left most line of the output.